# Vertical align Ionic Icons and Text

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

I want release a kind of date picker with the date in the middle and switch left/right for previous or next date. I have currently problems with formatting the view. I want vertical align the Ionic Icons (left & right) and the text `{{displayDate}}`. I have tried following but without the result I want.

**HTML**

```
   <ion-footer>
        <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 100%">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item text-center style="align-content: center!important">
              <ion-icon name="md-arrow-dropleft"  style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 10px"></ion-icon>
            <b> {{displayDate}} </b>
            <ion-icon name="md-arrow-dropright" style="font-size: 30px; margin-left: 10px"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </div>
          <ion-toolbar>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-footer>
```

**CSS**

```
b {
  color: #387ef5;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    }
```

How it looks currently:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
b {
  color: #387ef5;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Tested it. Sadly has no effect.

Comment: @Sandruna realy? give me link on u project. i have look this in browser inspector

Answer (score 0):

Try using this! Hope this works for you!

```
b {
  color: #387ef5;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```